# Cadsoft EAGLE Some objects extend outside the allowed board area

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, layout

I'm trying to Modify an eagle file that I have, it's a relatively simple circuit and I'm using the free version of Cad soft Eagle to do it. One of the components on the board is a 4 pin plug, I'm trying to add another 4pin plug and map it to one of the terminals. The circuit is small (2" x 1") and I am able to modify it, but when I try to add another 4 pin connector or copy the existing one, I get the following error "Some objects extend outside the allowed board area". which makes no sense, because the component is clearly within the board area.

Any idea how to get around this error?

Here is a screen shot of the layout
[image]

For some reason this is the only spot on the board where moving J2 does not throw that error, can't figure out if perhaps it's something weird with the component.

Comment: Make all layers visible and take a screen shot of where you are trying to place the component.

Comment: @DanLaks here is the layout

Comment: If the original file wasn't created with the free version of Eagle, try to locate the origin (0,0) of the canvas and move the whole board so that everything lies on the quadrant where both x,y are positive for all components, but not too far from the origin.

Comment: @apalopohapa I think it was created with pro ... the only problem with trying to move the entire board is that the group and move function also only works with pro

Comment: No, group and move works for all versions

Comment: ok, group and move worked ... you have to group it and then control right click on mac ... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the original file was created with the origin very far away from where the board was created. To fix the problem, group the objects, then control and right click (on mac) and select group and move ... the allowed me to move the entire board to 0,0